# Unable to Install Pylint in windows - python?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I am new to python, I installed python on windows in the following directory `C:\Program Files\Python36`, I am using `vscode` as IDE when I trying to run the following command in `integrated terminal`

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python" -m pip install pylint
```

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
>       **kwargs
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)
>     File "c:\program files\python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode)
>   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\python36\Lib\site-packages\colorama'

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Try running the command prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a permission issues:

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

You need to run the command as administrator.
You can Right Click on the command prompt (You can use for example `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`) and click "Run as administrator". Then execute `"C:\Program Files\Python36\python" -m pip install pylint`

It should solve your issue

Comment: Why does this solve the issue? You shouldn't need administrator access to perform this installation. This is handled by the application, not the OS. For example, you don't need administrator access to install a Firefox extension, which is similar to a library of new features.